# Stripping line edings before appending to a list?

Tags: python, list, line-endings

Ok I am writing a program that reads text files and goes through the different lines, the problem that I have encountered however is line endings (\n). My aim is to read the text file line by line and write it to a list and remove the line endings before it is appended to the list.

I have tried this:

```
thelist = []    
inputfile = open('text.txt','rU')    

for line in inputfile:
    line.rstrip()
    thelist.append(line)
```

Comment: note that it would be a better approach to just go through the lines once and use `line.rstrip()` on each iteration. No need for an intermediary list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rstrip` doesn't change its argument, it returns modified string, that's why you must write it so:

```
thelist.append(line.rstrip())
```

But you can write your code simpler:

```
with open('text.txt', 'rU') as inputfile:
    thelist = [x.rstrip() for x in inputfile]
```

Comment: Thanks Man, So simple I just couldn't seem to get it though.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable in Python.  All string methods return *new* strings, and don't modify the original one, so the line

```
line.rstrip()
```

effectively does nothing.  You can use a list comprehension to accomplish this:

```
with open("text.txt", "rU") as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in f]
```

Also note that it is stringly recommended to use the `with` statement to open (and implicitly close) files.

Comment: yeah I figured but I any other examples I had seen seemed overly long and I just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('text.txt', 'rU') as f: # Use with block to close file on block exit
    thelist = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

```
s = s.strip(' \t\n\r')
```

This will strip white spaces from both the beginning and the end of you string

Comment: The OP only wants to strip trailing `\n` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rstrip('\n')` on each line before appending to your list.

Answer (score 0):

`rstrip` returns a new string. It should be `line = line.rstrip()`. However, the whole code could be shorter:

```
thelist = list(map(str.rstrip, open('text.txt','rU')))
```

UPD: Note that just calling `rstrip()` trims all trailing whitespace, not just newline. But there is a concise way to do that too:

```
thelist = open('text.txt','rU').read().splitlines()
```

Comment: ...so long as the OP wants to trim all trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

In Python - strings are immutable - which means that operations return a **new** string, and don't modify the existing string. ie, you've got it right, but need to re-assign (or name a new variable) using `line = line.rstrip()`.